# tunable integers

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I wrote the following function which is based on pattern matching:

```
def replacingElem(lines: List[String], last10: String): List[String] = 
{
  if (lines.isEmpty) Nil else {
    val row = lines.head.split("[ \t]+")
    row(0).toInt match {
      case 10 => lines.head :: replacingElem(lines.tail, row(1))
      case 15 => (row(0) + " " + last10 + " " + row(2) + " " + row(3)) :: replacingElem(lines.tail, last10)
      case _ => lines.head :: replacingElem(lines.tail, last10)
    }
  }
}
```

My aim is to make the integers 10 and 15 tunable and to make them as arguments for the function. I made the following modifications :

```
def replaceIndex(lines: List[String], last10: String,a:Int,b:Int): List[String] = {
  if (lines.isEmpty) Nil else {
    val row = lines.head.split("[ \t]+")
    row(0).toInt match {
      case a => lines.head :: replaceIndex(lines.tail, row(1),a,b)
      case b => (row(0) + " " + last10 + " " + row(2) + " " + row(3)) :: replaceIndex(lines.tail, last10,a,b)
      case _ => lines.head :: replaceIndex(lines.tail, last10,a,b)
    }
  }
}
```

But I got compilations errors.

Answer (score 5):

Back-tics...

```
case `a` => ...
case `b` => ...
```

...tells the compiler, "Don't create new variables here, use the values in these existing variables."

The other option is to start the variable name with a capital letter.

```
def replaceIndex(lines:List[String], last10:String, A:Int, B:Int):List[String]=...
```

But I prefer the back-tics solution.

Comment: Aka only use stable identifiers